# how to order on post_IDs key not on value using WP_Query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i'm passing post_ids to WP_Query() like this

```
$result_post_ids = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT  DISTINCT auction_id 
                   FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "simple_auction_log 
                   WHERE userid = $user_id 
                   order by date DESC" , ARRAY_N);

  $args = array (
            'post__in' => $result_post_ids ,
            'post_type' => 'product' ,
            'posts_per_page' => $limit ,
            'paged' => $page ,
            'tax_query' => $category_filter , //category
            'orderby' => $order_by,
            'order' => $order
        );
```

the $result_post_ids array is like this

```
array (size=15)
  0 => string '175' (length=3)
  1 => string '148' (length=3)
  2 => string '169' (length=3)
  3 => string '176' (length=3)
  4 => string '170' (length=3)
  5 => string '205' (length=3)
  6 => string '142' (length=3)
  7 => string '168' (length=3)
  8 => string '132' (length=3)
  9 => string '173' (length=3)
  10 => string '177' (length=3)
  11 => string '84' (length=2)
  12 => string '171' (length=3)
  13 => string '128' (length=3)
  14 => string '82' (length=2)
```

so this is the order of ids i want to view but when passing the $args to WP_Query() is reorder the post ids on the value so he is displaying the post with the grater value first like this

```
 177 , 176 , ...
```

but i want to display on the order of the keys `0 , 1 , 2`  please any help and many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your `orderby` parameter to `post__in`:

```
$args = array (
    'post__in' => $result_post_ids ,
    'post_type' => 'product' ,
    'posts_per_page' => $limit ,
    'paged' => $page ,
    'tax_query' => $category_filter ,
    'orderby' => 'post__in',  // Order by the array passed in above
    'order' => $order
);
```

From [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters):

> `'post__in'` - Preserve post ID order given in the `post__in` array (available since Version 3.5)